# How to Implement the Pattern 2^n-1 using Bitwise Operators

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit

While programming with bitwise operations I had a doubt. That is,in my project at one point of time I need to set bits like this, if I type '1' it means the 1st bit is set. If I type '2' it means the first 2 bits are set.

So,

1-1 2-11 3-111 4-1111

Likewise it goes. From this I analyze the following pattern.That is 1-1,11-3,111-7,1111-15.

That is 2^1-1=1,2^2-1=3,2^3-1=7,...

Now I need to write bitwise operations for this format in a single Line.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

So far we've had "the main two answers" that you usually get to this question. They're different in their edge conditions. Assuming 32bit unsigned integers to take something common, the `(1u<<n)-1` answer can handle 0 through 31, and the `0xFFFFFFFF>>(32-n)` answer can handle 1 through 32.

A question that often arises then is, can we have 0 through 32?

And you can, but naturally it is more complicated, especially if you don't accept conditionals. The full range is easy to make by combining either approach with a ternary operator, but without that, there are still ways.

Note that `n=32` is the only case in which the bit `0b00100000` is set in `n`.

So one thing we can do is extract that bit, invert it, and shift it left (being careful not to execute an undefined shift), like this:

```
((n >> 5 ^ 1) << (n & 31)) - 1
```

Now if `n < 32`, it simplifies to the old `(1u << n) - 1`. If `n == 32`, it simplifies to `(0 << irrelevant) - 1`, where `irrelevant` happens to be 0 but we could have chosen anything from 0 through 31.

In some languages (notably C# and Java), shifting by the width of an integer or more is defined and the `& 31` can be removed. In some assembly languages, for example PowerPC, shifting by the width of an integer results in 0, in that case the assembly level equivalent of `(1u << n) - 1` would work as-is.

In other assembly languages there may be other tricks, often using special instructions that have no direct equivalent in high level languages. For example on x86 with BMI1:

```
or rax, -1
shl ecx, 8
bextr rax, rax, rcx
```

Or on x86 with BMI2:

```
or rax, -1
bzhi rax, rax, rcx
```

Comment: The question specifically mentions 1 as the first possibility so it's probably unnecessary handling 0. If you _did_ have to handle 0, that would simply be a special edge case up front like `if (bc == 0) return 0;`.

Comment: @paxdiablo I don't think it does. It doesn't specifically address the 0 or 32 cases, there's just a small list of examples. Perhaps neither are required, OP did seem to like both answers.

Comment: +1 for the answer. I have been using `(n == 32) ? 0xFFFFFFFF : (1 << n - 1)` for years, and looking for a branch-free solution. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

`1 << n` gives `2 ^ n`, so you may need this one for `2 ^ n - 1`:

```
static inline unsigned int test(int n)
{
    return (1u << n) - 1;
}
```

Comment: :Thanks.For your comaprision in this https://gist.github.com/starrify/abc948abe56e51b5c1e8

Comment: @VINAYAK Just want to remind you that only weirdos care about optimizing at such levels on such a maybe-not-often-used function. XD. If any other option provides better readability or similar good characteristics while runs slightly slower, choose the slower one as long as you're not doing an insane optimization engineer's job. :P

Answer (score 1):

With an unsigned int (let's say 32 bits), you can get the value from bitcount as follows:

```
value = 0xffffffffU >> (32-bitcount);
```

For example, let's use a `bitcount` of 3:

```
  0xffffffff >> (32-bitcount)
= 0xffffffff >> 29
= 0x00000007
```

The following program shows this in action:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int cvt (int bc) {
    return 0xffffffffU >> (32-bc);
}

int main (void) {
    for (int bc = 1; bc <= 32; bc++)
        printf ("%2d: 0x%08x %u\n", bc, cvt (bc), cvt (bc));
    return 0;
}
```

The output of that program shows that each subsequent bitcount adds one more `1-bit` on the right:

```
 1: 0x00000001 1
 2: 0x00000003 3
 3: 0x00000007 7
 4: 0x0000000f 15
 5: 0x0000001f 31
 6: 0x0000003f 63
 7: 0x0000007f 127
 8: 0x000000ff 255
 9: 0x000001ff 511
10: 0x000003ff 1023
11: 0x000007ff 2047
12: 0x00000fff 4095
13: 0x00001fff 8191
14: 0x00003fff 16383
:
30: 0x3fffffff 1073741823
31: 0x7fffffff 2147483647
32: 0xffffffff 4294967295
```

Comment: Hi it's interesting that your answer runs about 1/3 times slower than mine.. I'd love to post the timing and some analysis, shall I post them here in SO or elsewhere?

Comment: @starrify, I haven't worried about optimisation. Unless you have to do it millions of times a second, it's unlikely to matter. CPU time on my box (user+sys) doesn't register at all (less than 0.001s for all of the 32 input values) and that's with zero optimisation. 64,000 calls brings CPU time up to 0.016s. Any analysis would be better off looking at the resulting asm code rather than trying to use anecdotal evidence but you can add analysis to your answer if you wish. I'll reserve right of reply of course :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo Please view this: https://gist.github.com/starrify/abc948abe56e51b5c1e8 :) Yeah in most cases I don't care about perfomance neigher, however it's always fun to investigate.